# No such file or directory?

Tags: ruby, regex

Ruby is giving me this error:

```
C:/Ruby/new.rb:11:in `read': No such file or directory - m.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby/new.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

But I'm sure that there is such file, Here is my code:

```
text = File.read("m.txt").split('\n')
text.each do |x|
    x.to_i

    File.open("m.txt", "w") do |file| 
      file.gsub(x, x *10)
    end
end
```

The line that is generating this error:

```
text = File.read("m.txt").split('\n')
```

I have checked several examples, like this: [How can I read a file with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157207/how-can-i-read-a-file-with-ruby)

And tried things like:

```
File.open("m.txt", "r+") do |infile|
    while (line = infile.gets)
        line.to_i.gsub(line, line *10)
    end
end
```

But I'm still getting this error.

What I'm trying to do is:  I have some numbers in text file like

> 12.2
>    432.3
>    3.43
>    .342
>    ...

And I want to multiply each one by 10. Note I'm sure about the file and that it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the absolute path:

`text = File.read("C:/Ruby/m.txt").split('\n')`

since your current directory is not the same as your script's directory.

Alternatively, you should navigate to that specific folder and then run the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
text = File.read("C:/Ruby/m.txt").split('\n')
File.open("C:/Ruby/m.txt", "w") do |file|  
  text.each do |x|
    file.puts x.to_f * 10
  end       
end
```