# How to multiply each number in a text file by 10

Tags: ruby, regex

[I've been working on this for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444120/no-such-file-or-directory)

But whatever I try it modifies only the first line, while I want to multioly each number by 10.
For example:

> 1
>   2
>   3.3
>   4.5
>   .
>   .
>   .

Should be:

> 10
>   20
>   33
>   45

But what I'm getting is :

> 10.0

Only

I've brought this from a stackoverflow question, and modified it but still the same result:

```
f = File.open("c:/Ruby/m.txt", "r+")
f.each_line do |line|
  f.write( line.to_f * 10)
end
f.close
```

if I try to use f.puts I would get an error: puts is a private method? How can I multiply each number by 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lines = File.readlines("c:/Ruby/m.txt")
new_lines = lines.map { |line| (line.to_f * 10).to_i }

File.open("c:/Ruby/m.txt", "w") { |f| f.puts new_lines }
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind but why does map work here and not select, as per this [blog](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/01/ruby-map-collect-and-select.html) it should return true, false ....

Comment: @Mark read the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) for [`Enumerable#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

Comment: bjhaid, the example has no number with more than one decimal place, but it's not known if that is the case generally.  Consider modifying your answer so that `3.45 => 34.5`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland read the question he wants integers and not floating point values

Comment: You're probably right, though it could be interpreted that floats with no fractional part should be written to file without the decimal, but let's not dance on the head of pin.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd be better off reading the file first, and only then writing to it:

```
lines = File.readlines("c:/Ruby/m.txt").to_a
f = File.open("c:/Ruby/m.txt", "w")
lines.each do |line|
  f.write((line.to_f * 10).to_i)
end
f.close
```